# List all Directories that do not contain a file with Wildcard Match

Tags: powershell, filesystems, wildcard, directory-structure

I need to be able to list all of the directories in a root folder that do not contain a file which contains the string `merged`. So for example, if I run the script from the directory `C:\out`, I will get a list of all the folders inside of `C:\out` which do not match the wildcard `merged`.

**Example:**

**Tree:**

```
-c:\out
--c:\out\test123
---sample.meta
---sample_merged.meta
--c:\out\test456
---sample.meta
---sample_merged.meta
--c:\out\test789
---sample.meta
--c:\out\test013
---sample.meta
```

**Output:**

```
test789
test013
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx), [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx), and [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176955.aspx):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Directory |
Where-Object { -not (Get-ChildItem $_ -File -Recurse -Filter *merged*) } |
Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
```

Below is an explanation of what each line does:

1. Get all directories in the current directory.
2. Set up a filter that searches recursively through each directory for file names that contain the string `merged`. Only pass on the directory if none are found.
3. Get the `Name` and `LastWriteTime` attributes of each directory.

Note too that you can write it more concisely if you want:

```powershell
gci -dir | ? { !(gci $_ -file -recur -filter *merged*) } | select name, *w*time
```

Comment: This is perfect! Is there also a way I can list the last modified date next to the names tabbed out?

Answer (score 0):

Pull a directory listing for the target, then filter against a listing of the target folder to not contain the file you're filtering for.

```
$BaseDir = "C:\out"
$FilterFile = "sample_merged.meta"
GCI $BaseDir -Directory | ?{!(GCI $_.FullName | Select -Expand Name) -Contains $FilterFile}|Select -Expand Name
```

That should give you the desired output. Change the last `Name` to `FullName` to get the entire path, not just the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

For a batch version

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions
    for /d %%a in ("c:\out\*") do (
        dir /b /a-d "%%~fa\*merged*" >nul 2>nul || echo %%~ta %%~nxa
    )
```

It simple iterates the folders inside `c:\out`, and for each of them a `dir` command for a `*merged*` file is executed. If the command fails the timestamp and name of folder is echoed to console.