# Find directories two levels down that do not contain certain file

Tags: powershell

I have done some Windows batch scripting, but I have never worked with PowerShell, so I am looking for some startup help.
I would like to

- parse a directory tree
- find all the directories two levels down that do not contain folder.jpg
- write the list of these directories to a text file

So far I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661751/list-all-directories-that-do-not-contain-a-file-with-wildcard-match) which addresses part of the question. I have also found that Get-ChildItem \*\*\* should get me to the directories two levels down.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me put this together.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is a bit too much of a "please write my script" request. Why not share the actual code you have managed so far? We'd rather help you learn than just give you the solution.

Comment: Hint 1: Use the code from that other solution to find folders which don't contain "folder.jpg". Look at the final `Select-Object` cmdlet and use that to return a unique list of DirectoryNames.

Comment: Hint 2: Once you have the list of full DirectoryNames, you could use `Resolve-Path -Relative` to give you the path relative to your current location, and then look for how many backslashes there are. It may be that someone will come up with a cleverer way to calculate directory depth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `Get-Child`, `Foreach-Object`, `Test-Path`, `Join-Path` and `Write-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem  *\*\* -Directory | ForEach-Object {if(!(Test-Path(Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath "folder.jpg"))) {Write-Output $_}}
```

This will write all the `DirectoryInfo` object where the file doesn't exist to the pipeline. You can then opt to write them to a file.